# Azure Cloud Service - Configure Session from RoleEnvironment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session, web-config, azure-cloud-services

Our application is hosted as a Cloud Service in Azure and we have all our connection strings and other connection-like settings defined in the ServiceConfiguration files.  We are also using a Redis Cache as the session state store.  We are trying to specify the Redis Cache host and access key in the ServiceConfig and then use those values for the deployment depending on where the bits land.  The problem is session is defined in the web.config and we can't pull RoleEnvironment settings into the web.config.

We tried altering the web.config in the Application_Startup method but get errors that access is denied to the web.config on startup, which makes sense.

We don't really want to write deployment scripts to give the Network Service user access to the web.config.

Is there a way to setup session to use a different Redis Cache at runtime of the application?

[image]

The error that we are getting is "Access to the path 'E:\sitesroot\0\web.config' is denied'. I read an article that gave some examples on how to give the Network Service user access to the web.config as part of the role starting process and did that and then now we have access to the file but now get the following error "Unable to save config to file 'E:\sitesroot\0\web.config'."

Comment: Hello, Can you show the part of the Application_Startup that opens the web.config ? Along with the error being generated?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the code.  This gets called in from the Application_Startup method in the Global.asax file

Comment: so you are getting the error because this piece of code will make the application to restart everytime. It does not make sense to do it that way you dont even check if you have the information there already. So let me ask you this. Is there any particular reason that you want to do this with every app startup ?

Comment: I'm not married to this way by any means.  All we are trying to do is be able to define the session state provider information AFTER the project has been built.  We are trying to be able to deploy the application bits to different environments and those environments require different end points for the session state provider. Since it appears the only place to define the session state provider is the web.config we are trying to alter the web.config after the cloud service package as been created.

Comment: I dont have access to my azure web site at the moment but if i remember correctly you are allowed to make changes to the web.config before deployment from the azure portal. If not that if you are using some type of CI/CD you could implement the changes through one of the steps of your deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up being able to solve this using the ServerManager API in the WebRole.OnStart method.  We did something like this:

```
using (var server = new ServerManager())
{    
    try
    {
        Site site = server.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web"];
        string physicalPath = site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath;
        string webConfigPath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, "web.config");

        var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(webConfigPath);

        var redisCacheProviderSettings = doc.Descendants("sessionState").Single().Descendants("providers").Single().Descendants("add").Single();

        redisCacheProviderSettings.SetAttributeValue("host", RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("SessionRedisCacheHost"));
        redisCacheProviderSettings.SetAttributeValue("accessKey", RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("SessionRedisCacheAccessKey"));
        redisCacheProviderSettings.SetAttributeValue("ssl", "true");
        redisCacheProviderSettings.SetAttributeValue("throwOnError", "false");

        doc.Save(webConfigPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error
    }    
}
```